# Retrieving gmail contact's photo

Tags: javascript, gmail

I am trying to retrieve the photo images of all my gmail contacts from javascript.

Using https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/

When I try to make an authorized AJAX GET request to the image url, I get the following error message:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load . Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This is how I am making the request:

```
$.ajax({ url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/atameem%40spokeo.com/16e8f6a1892842c7", data: authParams, success: function(data) { console.log(data); } });
```

The GET URL with access token that I see in the browser network tab is :

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/atameem%40spokeo.com/16e8f6a1892842c7?state=&access_token=ya29.AHEGYGMYP-G_3FmAxzDuWD3a4j4_mBVY&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&alt=json

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is error is shown when you try to make an ajax call from some other domain other than the request. You cannot make cross-domain ajax call to retrieve the response. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS .

However you can set headers to allow Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing (CORS): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

You can request any file through credentials as well:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true
});
```

CORS is being supported in Latest Major Browsers. You can check if your browsers supports by the following code snippet:

```
//Detect browser support for CORS
if ('withCredentials' in new XMLHttpRequest()) {
    /* supports cross-domain requests */
    document.write("CORS supported (XHR)");
}
else{
  if(typeof XDomainRequest !== "undefined"){
     //Use IE-specific "CORS" code with XDR
     document.write("CORS supported (XDR)");
  }else{
     //Time to retreat with a fallback or polyfill
     document.write("No CORS Support!");
  }
}
```